# Python - Sort a Linked List by its attribute(s)

Tags: python, linked-list

I've constructed a Singly Linked List in Python and I want to sort this LL based on its particular *attribute*. For example, I have a Linked List of *arrays* which have a *price* and *rating* attribute in one of its particular indices.

In my particular case, I want to sort a restaurant's by its price or by its rating in *descending* order.

Here's my attempt:

```
  def sort(self, sort_type):
    if self.head_node == None:
      print("Nothing to sort!")
      return
    ll_sorted = False
    while not ll_sorted:
      ll_sorted = True
      prev = self.head_node
      current = prev.get_next_node()
      while current.value != None:
        prev_value = int(float(prev.value[sort_type]))
        current_value = int(float(current.value[sort_type]))
        if prev_value < current_value:
          ll_sorted = False
          temp = prev
          prev = current
          current = temp
        current = current.get_next_node()
```

So an example entry in my linked list can look something like this:

`['cafe', 'Zardoz Cafe', '4', '2', '6202 Alameda']`

At index 2, we can pull the *price* and at index 3, we can pull the *rating* of the restaurant (these restaurants are fictional). Therefore, in the code presented above, the `sort_type` is the particular index I pass to either sort by price or rating (by user input).

When I'm sorting this, I don't want to change the *data* of the nodes, but rather I want to swap the *nodes* with respect to their attribute (i.e. price or rating).

I had success swapping the *data* of the nodes, but that ruins the integrity of a node's attribute and does not produce expected results.

I've been trying to figure this out on my own, but I can't seem to wrap my head around this. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why are you using your own linked list? Is this for learning?

Comment: Also, consider using a class to represent your restautants instead of an array.

Comment: yes, this is for learning purposes and I am currently taking a data structures course. the restaurant data was presented in an a 2-D array. if i had the choice, I personally wouldn't represent my data inside arrays, but rather in objects. thanks for any help!

Comment: I think you can use a class to store the intermediate data. Ask your professor... if it's for a DS course, I'd be surprised if they wouldn't let you.